# Data Table column filters not displaying properly in Shiny (Using DT package)

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a data table I am rendering in shiny using the DT package. Each individual column has a filter at the top. All column filters are working but the formatting is somewhat strange.
 [Screenshot of column filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCwhs.png)

As you can see some of the filters have the word "All" inside them and these function correctly, when you type in them the word you are typing shows up.

However some of the others do not and when I type in these the filtering mechanism does work (as in the correct rows are filtered out) but you cannot see what filter you typed in. It seems as though the cursor is way to the left in the box and not visible.

The code I use to render the data table is below:

```
DT::renderDataTable(X,
                    options = list(pageLength = 10, 
                                   searching = TRUE,
                                   autoWidth = TRUE,
                                   columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all"))
                                   ),
                   filter = "top"
                   )
```

Answer (score 2):

(Still) Trying to solve a different issue, I set `padding` to zero in CSS for `.has-feedback .form-control` and at least I can now see "All" in every filter cell. More specifically:

```
.has-feedback .form-control {
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Hope it helps.

P.S. It's easy to play around with this stuff using the right-click & 'inspect' functionality of Chrome (and I guess Firefox).

Comment: For those who are confused, you can apply this CSS by putting this line in your UI `tags$head(tags$style(HTML( '.has-feedback .form-control { padding-right: 0px;}' )))`

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge this is a known bug for DT::renderDataTable as long as you use server-side processing (which is the default setting for DT::renderDataTable) for bigger tables (*i.e.* many columns). If you set ***server = FALSE***, the filters should be shown properly...

Comment: I tried adding the server=FALSE setting, however it did not seem to resolve the issue, for some of the columns the "All" is visible and when text is typed in you can see it however for others it still seems to be typing in there as the filters work but the text I am typing cant be seen.